# Disable flip in Boostrap 4 Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover, popper.js

I would like the popover to always stick on the same position and doesn't change when scrolling:
https://jsfiddle.net/eloyrubio/aq9Laaew/251011/

```
 var options = {
  placement: 'top',
  title: 'I should be on top',
  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lobortis nisl et metus varius lobortis. Sed sit amet posuere velit. Curabitur vel blandit mauris, a rutrum ante. Praesent sit amet orci viverra arcu sodales posuere.',
  html: false
};

$('#po1').popover(options).popover('show');
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEq0I.png)

I am using Bootstrap 4.1.3 and I saw that Popover extends Tooltip:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/popover.js#L70

And here is the Tooltip code:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/tooltip.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add another option of `fallbackPlacement`:

```
var options = {
  placement: 'top',
  fallbackPlacement: ['top'],
  flip: 'top',
  title: 'I should be on top',
  content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lobortis nisl et metus varius lobortis. Sed sit amet posuere velit. Curabitur vel blandit mauris, a rutrum ante. Praesent sit amet orci viverra arcu sodales posuere.',
  html: false
};
```

It passes that value to `flip.behavior` ([see more](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/tooltip.js#L292)).

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/251047/

Comment: Thank you @falinsky . Is there a way to partially hide the popover instead of overlapping the button: https://jsfiddle.net/eloyrubio/aq9Laaew/251494/ ?

Comment: Thanks mate, helped me a lot. took me a while to find but now that i am here ;)